# How to continue compilation process?

Tags: linux

I encountered with the error while i was compiling a package

```
  curl-config : command not found
```

Does anybody know how to fix this problem ?

Thank you

Comment: Google the error message.  It might tell you what package you're missing.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the development package for `libcurl` or `curl`.

Comment: something like : sudo apt-get install libcurl3 ?

Comment: More like `sudo apt-get install libcurl3-dev`.

Comment: do i have synaptic package manager by default in ubuntu (13.10) or i should get it first by the way ?

Comment: Whatever works for you :-) I don't like the package manager because it takes too long to get things done but then, I'm a command line junkie, so you probably shouldn't listen to me.

Comment: well i am a beginner in linux , so i have no idea about what works for me ... so as i am not sure about the name i am looking for ( i mean libcurl* ), i think maybe such a package may help ! that's all ....well i really don't know exactly what i am doing !!! it feels like walking totally blind !! haha :)

Comment: @nazanin: That's how we all start. You stumble around, make mistakes, realize what you shouldn't have done and do it better next time. After 200'000 years of human history, it's safe to say that this is the best way we have to learn :-)

Comment: Aaron i just typed  apt-cache install *curl*  and it didn't work !!! i remember when i was getting netCDF it worked ! can you please help me why ? many thanks

Comment: 1. I told you to install something else. 2. Never again in your whole life say "didn't work". Say what you did, what you expected and what happened instead (and if you saw an error message, then don't keep it to yourself). :-)

Comment: could it happen because of new release of ubuntu?

Comment: this is the error in updating process **E: GPG error: http://dl.google.com stable InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?) **

Comment: i mentioned your name ! it deleted it ! ha ;)

Comment: The error `Failed to fetch security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/… 404 Not Found` means something is wrong with your system. Go over to http://askubuntu.com/, post the command you ran and the error message to get some help.